# How can I change a text menu link to an imge using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu link that I need to be replaced with an image, I am trying to do this by just using the console for now.

The code that I have been trying to use is this:

```js
(document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("http://prototypes.example.com/test/MW/long-logo.png");
      document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content").setAttribute("src", screenshot);
    }
  });
```

```html
<ul class="main-sub-menu content-width">
  <li class="sub-menu-content">
  <a href="http://www.example.net/currency-forecast-tool" target="">Currency forecast tool
  </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The code throws no errors but does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: You created a snippet. Please add relevant html and styles to give us a [mcve]. For example getElements is plural, so you need to loop or use `document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0]` for the first one  - if sub-menu-content is a link, you need to use `document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0].innerHTML='<img src="' + screenshot + '"/>';`

Comment: You can't, but you can insert an image inside one, using `anchorElement.appendChild(imageTag)` ... still, provide a minimal working code snippet

Comment: Is sub-menu-content an Image where u are trying to add src??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `li` doesn't have a `src` attribute, and assigning it one won't make it an `img`

You can assign it a `background-image` though

```
(document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("http://prototypes.example.com/test/MW/long-logo.png");
      document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + screenshot + ')');
    }
  });
```

---

*As a side note, the `getElementsByClassName()` return a collection of elements, and you would need something like `document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0]` to target a specific element. A suggestion would be to use `querySelector` instead, as in*

```
(document.querySelector("sub-menu-content"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("http://prototypes.example.com/test/MW/long-logo.png");
      document.querySelector("sub-menu-content").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + screenshot + ')');
    }
});
```

---

If you need an `img`, you could do something like this, using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), which will insert an `img` inside the anchor `a`:

```
var link = document.querySelector(".sub-menu-content a");
link.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<img src="' + screenshot + '"/>');
```

A [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) representing the position relative to the *element*; must be one of the following strings:

- `'beforebegin'`: Before the element itself.
- `'afterbegin'`: Just inside the element, before its first child.
- `'beforeend'`: Just inside the element, after its last child.
- `'afterend'`: After the element itself.

---

Or replace the anchor's content using `innerHTML`:

```
var link = document.querySelector(".sub-menu-content a");
link.innerHTML = '<img src="' + screenshot + '"/>';
```

---

Updated based on a comment, showing how to use a CSS selector to find a specific element

```js
var screenshot = "http://placehold.it/200x100";
var link = document.querySelector(".sub-menu-content:nth-child(3) a");
link.innerHTML = '<img src="' + screenshot + '"/>';
```

```html
<ul class="main-sub-menu content-width">
  <li class="sub-menu-content">
    <a href="http://www.example.net/currency-forecast-tool" target="">Currency forecast tool 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu-content">
    <a href="http://www.example.net/currency-forecast-tool" target="">Currency forecast tool 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu-content">
    <a href="http://www.example.net/currency-forecast-tool" target="">Currency forecast tool 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu-content">
    <a href="http://www.example.net/currency-forecast-tool" target="">Currency forecast tool 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the issue is that there are of course multiple elements with the same class name 'sub-menu-content' so the JS is finding the wrong element to change. Is there a way of targeting just that specific element in question.

Comment: @MattWallis With `querySelector()` you can use a CSS selector, and find e.g. the 4th `.sub-menu-content` with `document.querySelector(".sub-menu-content:nth-child(4)")`

Comment: @MattWallis I added a simplified sample in the end of my answer on how-to.

Answer (score 0):

You are failing most probably because of the way you are using to access the DOM element you want to set the attribute on.

`document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")` will get you the live node list of all the matching elements. Even if there is one, it'd still be in that list.

You have no function of `setAttribute` on a list. So you better access the element of the live node list to apply `setAttribute`. Something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0].setAtt..
```

Or if you always want to select the first one, you can also use

```
document.querySelector('.sub-menu-content').setAttribute(..)
```

Just noticed that you are trying to set `src` on `li`. This won't turn it into an image.

You can add that image as it's background. Something like

```
document.querySelector('.sub-menu-content').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + screenshot + ')';
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `getElementsByClassName` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).
From the oficial docs:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

So, if you want to `setAttribute` to your DOM element, you should specify like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0]`.
 So your code would look something similar to:

```
(document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("http://prototypes.infopro-insight.com/test/MW/long-logo.png");
        document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu-content")[0].setAttribute("src", screenshot);
    }                                                                  
});
```